# Trying to solve js koan / about_array.js

Tags: javascript

Im new to js and I cannot solve this problem.

```
test("splice", function() {
    var daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    var workingWeek = daysOfWeek.splice(__);
    ok(workingWeek.equalTo([__]), 'what is the value of workingWeek?');
    ok(daysOfWeek.equalTo([__]), 'what is the value of daysOfWeek?');
});
```

My try was below but it's not working.

```
test("splice", function() {
    var daysOfWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    var workingWeek = daysOfWeek.splice(5,6);
    ok(workingWeek.equalTo([5]), 'what is the value of workingWeek?');
    ok(daysOfWeek.equalTo([2]), 'what is the value of daysOfWeek?');
});
```

Could someone provide me any clue one this?

Comment: You know what the [`splice` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does? And you know that `[5]` is an array literal with nothing but a number in it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Probable source: https://github.com/liammclennan/JavaScript-Koans/blob/master/topics/about_arrays.js

Comment: Woah...this is my first time to ask question here and I'm really surprised how fast I got comments...! =)

>Bergi
Thank you for your comment! I will try your advise right now. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

> [The] `Array` `splice` method
>
> `array.splice(index, howMany, […])`
>
> Changes the content of an array, adding new elements while removing old elements
>
> Returns […] an array containing the removed elements.

So your current code will remove 6 elements, starting with the 6th (on index `5`, i.e. `'Saturday'`). That's a little too much, removing only 2 should be enough though it won't make any difference here - they are at the end of the array.

What you proably want to achieve is that

```
ok(workingWeek.equalTo(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']), 'what is the value of workingWeek?');
// though it makes no practical sense, you are using splice():
ok(daysOfWeek.equalTo(['Saturday', 'Sunday']), 'what is the value of daysOfWeek?');
```

I'll leave the task on changing the arguments to your `splice(…)` call up to you :-)